# Force gif to reload after mouse leave

Tags: javascript, html, css, gif

On my website I have several images that loop through a GIF animation on mouse hover, and return to a static image when the mouse leaves the picture.

I'd like the gif to play from its first frame when the mouse hovers. However, if I hover over a picture, move the mouse away, and hover again, the image will turn to the gif continuing from the last frame it was on.

Here is my HTML code:

```
<img id="menugif">
```

My CSS:

```
#menugif
{
    padding-top: 15px;
    height: 115px;
    width: 125px;
    content:url(../images/Hulk.png);
    float: left;
}
#menugif:Hover
{
    cursor:pointer; 
    content:url('../images/Hulk.gif');
    float: left;
}
```

I'd be grateful to any solution, including Javascripts! Thank you all :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a cheap way to fix it, but to resolve I did this:

Each HTML gif has its own ID:

```
<a id="single_image1" href="#"><img id="menugifHulk" src="images\hulk.png"></a>
```

Each one of these has it's own style, like so:

```
#menugifHulk
        {
            padding-top: 15px;
            height: 115px;
            width: 125px;
            float: left;
        }
```

And then each element has its own JavaScript:

```
var img = document.getElementById('menugifHulk');
img.addEventListener('mouseleave', function () {
    var imageUrl = img.src;
    img.src = "";
    img.setAttribute('src', 'images/Hulk.png');
}, false);
img.addEventListener('mouseover', function () {
    img.setAttribute('src', 'images/Hulk.gif');
}, false);
```

The java was in a function like this:

```
function GifReset()
{
    var img = document.getElementById('menugifHulk');
    img.addEventListener('mouseleave', function () {
        var imageUrl = img.src;
        img.src = "";
        img.setAttribute('src', 'images/Hulk.png');
    }, false);
    img.addEventListener('mouseover', function () {
        img.setAttribute('src', 'images/Hulk.gif');
    }, false);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

try this:

```
var img = document.getElementById('menugif');
img.addEventListener('mouseleave', function () {
    this.style.content = this.style.content;
}, false);
```

Comment: Please can you write me a JSFiddle? I cannot get this to work at all after loads of experimenting :( Thank you for the reply!

Comment: @Freddie currently content:url is not supported by all browsers... (e.g FF 45 doesn't).. so if You do not care...
get a look at [that](http://www.freakstyle.it/tmp/gif/) ... otherwise You need to opt for more traditional one:
a) [js bases, img tag](http://www.freakstyle.it/tmp/gif2/) ; b) [css based, div tag](http://www.freakstyle.it/tmp/gif3/)
 hope it helps!

Comment: Thanks for the help! Unfortunatly, this is not working for me. I tried your site you linked on Google Chrome and the gif does not reset to the start on the second hover. This can be seen below, where I replaced the banana dancing gif with a timer gif: https://i.imgur.com/TWvhexL.gifv

Comment: U`re right. In the js based example the mouseover listener before setting again the gif url must reset it. Now seem to work as You expect. See it [here](http://www.freakstyle.it/tmp/gif2)

Answer (score 0):

I think that [this tutorial](http://embed.ly/docs/tutorials/gif) cover completely your case, both CSS and Javascript side even if you are gonna require a couple of extra libraries (jQuery and Font Awesome).

Comment: Please can you write me a JSFiddle? I cannot get this to work at all after loads of experimenting :( Thank you for the reply!